# Importing accounts and contacts from Salescloud into Marketing cloud via import activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud

When i am importing Accounts(standard account object) from Salescloud in marketing cloud via import activity it's getting saved under My Data extensions, however when i import contacts (standard account object) from Salescloud, its getting stored under salesforce data extension. Any specific reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

With the Marketing Cloud Connector, Contacts and Leads are objects that can be sent to so a Salesforce Data Extension is created when imported so it could be used as the target for a send.  The Account object can not be the target for a send which is why it isn't created as a Salesforce Data Extension.